# Get ProjectItems for Partial Class through CodeModel

Tags: .net, class, partial, envdte

I have seen looking for a way to get the list of ProjectItems (files) for a known class, which generated from several partial classes. I use CodeModel to search for a class and accessing the ProjectItem to do stuff, which works fine for normal classes. But when it comes to partial classes, the ProjectItem property give one file but dont provide the other files which make this partial class.
How can I access the other ProjectItems that make up the class , through partial classes

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the original poster did find the answer to the question on the [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f68d5fab-ebf6-4e67-8ea7-dca265212d80/get-projectitems-for-partial-class-through-codemodel). Linking it back here as well for reference.

> Given an EnvDTE.CodeClass, cast it to EnvDTE80.CodeClass2 and use the CodeClass2.Parts property to get the other (class) code element, whose ProjectItem property gives you the file of the partial class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing so recursively? If you just query EnvDTE.Project.ProjectItems you'll get only the project items at the first level, you'll have to EnvDTE.ProjectItem.ProjectItems as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it recursive to iterate through all the items in the project (as you have mentioned, with EnvDTE.ProjectItem.ProjectItems). But my original questions is about reaching the Project item through a CodeModel reference. For normal classes, once we found the Class in the Code Model, we can get the ProjectItem property of it. But for Partial classes I was hoping that property to provide the list of project items for that class.